# Change Case of Programming Syntax

Tags: syntax, notepad++, case, sublimetext3

I was wondering if there was a simpler way to change the case of just the highlighted colored programming text (For In While Do Set etc) in one go by color using notepad++ or sublime text. So for example change the case of all the blue text in a batch file test.bat:

```
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c 
ECHO(0x09"') DO SET "TAB=%%A"
ECHO This is a %TAB%
```

The syntax would be changed to title case like:

```
Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "delims=" %%A In ('forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c 
Echo(0x09"') Do Set "TAB=%%A"
Echo This is a %TAB%
```

I currently do this by Right Clicking and then selecting Plugin Commands> Copy Text with Syntax Highlighting from the context menu, copying this text to Microsoft word and saving it as an html file, opening the html file in notepad++ for editing and then pasting `text-transform: uppercase;` under the line `color:blue;` and then opening it again in word (not in edit mode) and finally copying it to notepad++ but would like to know if there is a simpler way without looking up each individual word but instead just batch formatting words of a similar color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime has an internal command called `title_case` to perform this manipulation, which is available from the menu as `Edit > Convert Case > Title Case` or from the command palette as `Convert Case: Title Case`.

So if all of the keywords in the document were selected, you could use that command to perform the operation. You would probably have to do it in batches (pun mildly intended), such as putting the cursor in `SETLOCAL` and repeatedly pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to select all of the instances, then cycle back and do the next keyword.

To automate the process a little better, a simple plugin can be created that selects all of the keywords and runs the command, so that you can perform the bulk of the operation in one simple step.

An example of that is the following, which you can use by selecting `Tools > Developer > New Plugin...` from the menu, replacing the stub code with the code below, and then saving in the location Sublime will default to as something like `dos_batch_case_fix.py` or something similar (only the location and extension matter):

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


# A list of extra words to change the title case for that aren't considered
# keywords by the dos batchfile syntax.
_extra_words = ["do", "in"]


class BatchTitleCaseCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    """
    For a dos batch file, convert the case of all keywords and all found
    instances of the words in _extra_words to title case.
    """
    def run(self, edit):
        # Save the current selection, then clear it
        saved_sel = list(self.view.sel())
        self.view.sel().clear()

        # Find everything that the syntax thinks is a keyword and add it to
        # the selection
        for region in self.view.find_by_selector("keyword"):
            self.view.sel().add(region)

        # Convert the list of extra words to a regular expression and add all
        # whole word matches to the selection.
        regex = r"\b({0})\b".format("|".join(_extra_words))
        for region in self.view.find_all(regex, sublime.IGNORECASE):
            self.view.sel().add(region)

        # Convert the selection to title case.
        self.view.run_command("title_case")

        # Restore the selection to what it was on entry.
        self.view.sel().clear()
        for region in saved_sel:
            self.view.sel().add(region)


    def is_enabled(self):
        return self.view.match_selector(0, "source.dosbatch")
```

This implements a new command named `batch_title_case` that is only active in batch files. It saves the current selection, then selects all of the keywords (as determined by the syntax currently in use), runs the command to change the case, then puts the original selection back. You can bind this command to a key the same as you would for any other internal command.

Since this uses the syntax of the current file to detect what a keyword is, it doesn't catch things like `IN` and `DO` because (at least currently) the Sublime syntax for Batch files doesn't think those are keywords.

For that reason, this also shows how you could handle those sorts of words. The code here does a case insensitive whole word search for a list of words (represented in `_extra_words`) and selects those as well as the selected text.

This is semi-dangerous in that unlike the keyword search by syntax scope, the regex search will find those words anywhere, including inside of strings where they might not represent keywords but just regular words instead.

As such it's probably a good idea to use this on a copy of the file (or be able to `undo`) and verify that it hasn't done something that you didn't otherwise expect.

I would imagine that a visual inspection would be much less effort than the solution you're currently using.

---

### Potential changes

If desired, the plugin above could be modified to remove the portions that save and restore the selection along with executing the `title_case` command; in that case the command would only alter the selection in the file to the words that it thinks that it needs to title case and allow yo to take the action manually.

Note that if you work with a really large file that contains a lot of keywords, having that many simultaneous selections may slow things down a bit.

---

### Invoking the command

The plugin above creates a command named `batch_title_case`. There are a variety of ways to execute the command, depending on how you want to proceed. Where the `User` package is mentioned below, you can use the `Preferences > Browse Packages` command from the menu to locate it. The `User` package is the location where the plugin above is stored, since Sublime defaults to that location when you use `Developer > New Plugin`.

#### Via a key binding

Using `Preferences > Key Bindings`, you can add a custom binding to the right hand side of the window that references the command:

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+s"],
    "command": "batch_title_case",
},
```

#### Via the Command Palette

The command can be added to the command palette by adding a file of type `sublime-commands` to your `User` package with the following contents (e.g. `MyCustomCommands.sublime-commands`). The `caption` will specify how the command appears:

```
[
    { "command": "batch_title_case", "caption": "Command Caption Here" },
]
```

***Note:*** As written above, the command is only enabled for a batch file, and the Command Palette only shows you available commands, so in non-batch files the command will not appear in the command palette.

#### Via the context menu

The command can be added to the right click context menu by creating a file named `Context.sublime-menu` in your `User` package; if such a file already exists, add only the `{ ... }` line to the appropriate place in the existing file. The `caption` will specify how the command appears:

```json
[
    { "command": "batch_title_case", "caption": "Command Caption Here" },
]
```

***Note:*** As written above, the command is only enabled for a batch file, so in non-batch files the command in the menu will appear grayed out. To hide the context menu item in files that it doesn't apply to, add the following lines to the plugin code above under `is_enabled()`:

```python
    def is_visible(self):
        return self.is_enabled()
```

Comment: What if I just wanted to have it select all keywords of the same color.  I can do the title change from the menu but want to select all of the same type/color. That would be just up to line `for region in self.view.find_all(regex, sublime.IGNORECASE):
            self.view.sel().add(region)` right?

Comment: Yes, if you just want to select them but take the action manually, you can drop the part that runs the command, as well as the code that would restore the selection (otherwise it will have no visible effect).

Comment: Saved it to Sublime Text\Data\Packages\User\SelectSimilarSyntax.py without the regex or extra words as well just to be safe but looking for a way to add the command to the the mouse right click context menu.

Comment: I added some invocation options to the answer, including how to add it to the context menu.

Comment: I added `{ "command": "Select_Similar_Syntax", "caption": "Select Similar Syntax" },` to Context.sublime-menu and the plugin was SelectSimilarSyntax.py with `class SelectSimilarSyntaxCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):` however the context menu item `Select Similar Syntax` is grayed out when right clicking on a selected colored keyword.  Maybe it's somehow not regarding bat files correctly.  How do I expand to all files as I have removed the batch file specific extra words and regex and only want it for keywords as recognized by sublime text for whatever current language I am using.

Comment: Sublime converts the class name to the command name by making the first character lower case, converting every remaining upper case character to an underscore and lower case letter, and throwing away the `_command` suffix (if it appears). So in your case `SelectSimilarSyntaxCommand` would convert to `select_similar_syntax` (i.e. your case is wrong above).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177236/discussion-between-smashpoint-and-odatnurd).